# Show Progress Icon Image on Input submit click MVC5

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-3

I want to show Progress Icon Image till My registration get completes.

My view code is as

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("RegisterStudent", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { }))
{
 @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", id = "txtname", placeholder = "Name" } })              
  <input type="submit"  value="submit" />
}

<script>
    $('input[type = submit]').click(function(){
        $.blockUI({ css: {
            border: 'none',
            padding: '15px',
            backgroundColor: '#000',
            opacity: .6
        } });
    });
</script>
```

When I click on input button I want to show the progress image till registration on controller side gets complete and after completion of registration the progress image should get disappear

Comment: Why not use ajax ? Then you can show whatever graphics until you get a response from your server call.

Comment: No I don't want to use ajax. Is it not possible in this way?

Comment: If you do a normal form submit, you are submitting the form. Whatever block UI graphics you start, use might see for a fraction of a second and then will see the response from the server. Did you try your code  ? What is happening then ?

Comment: I had tried for  $('input[type = submit]').click(function()   but it is not showing anything on submit click

Comment: If you want to show a progress bar like block ui, you need to use ajax to do a form submit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case If You need to show Progress icon Image on submit click simply do below things

**View Content**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("RegisterStudent", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { }))
{
 @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", id = "txtname", placeholder = "Name" } })  
<input type="submit" id="submitfilteration" class="btn btn-default btn-browse" value="Register as Tutor" />
<input type="submit" id="gotocontroller" style="display:none" />
}

<div class="loader" style="display:none"><div class="loader_inner"><img src="/Content/images/loading-gear.gif" id="gif" style="width: 100px;"></div></div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
        $('#submitfilteration').click(function (evt) {
            evt.preventDefault();
            var $form = $('form');
            if ($form.valid()) {// Will Check if any validation occurs
                $(".loader").show();
                $("#gotocontroller").click();// Here then after redirect to same or other page to make loader hide from controller side
            }
        });
</script>
```

**Style**

```
<style>
.loader {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    z-index: 9999;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
}
.loader_inner {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -50px;
    margin-top: -50px;
}
</style>
```

**In Case Of AJAX**

```
 function approvestudentrequest(id) {
    $(".loader").show();              
    $.ajax({
        url: '/Account/approvestudentrequest',
        type: 'GET', // You can use GET
        data: { 'StudentRequestId': '"abc"'},
        dataType: "json",
        context: this,
        cache: false,
        success: function (data) {
            if (data == "Success") {                   
                $(".loader").hide();
            }
            else { 
         $(".loader").hide(); 
          alert('Some Error'); }
        },
        error: function (request) {
            $(".loader").hide();
            console.log(request);                
        }
    });       
}
```